# jQuery dataTables column filter CSS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am having a problem with my column filter, it is showing up but between my grey area of the datatable and my second thead row. It is functioning properly except for it has no background and no styling.

[image: Image of datatable]

```
function tablefill(selected) {
    $.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';
    $('.advsearchbar').show();
    $('#stable').show();

    $('#table_id').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": '/php/connect/searchtablequery.php',
        "bProcessing": true,
        //"sScrollY": "500px",`
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "db", "value": selected });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            {"sWidth": "40%","mData": "calldate" },
            {"sWidth": "30%","sClass": "system", "sType": "string", "mData": "uniqueid" },
            {"sWidth": "150%","sType": "string", "mData": "clid" },
            {"sWidth": "10%","sType": "string", "mData": "lastapp" },
            {"sWidth": "100%","sType": "string", "mData": "dst" },
            {"sWidth": "50%","sType": "string", "mData": "disposition" },
            {"sWidth": "5%","sType": "string", "mData": "duration_in_mins_and_secs" }, ],
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"lrT>t<"F"ip>',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "text",
                    "sButtonText": "Refresh",
                    "sButtonClass": "refresh",
                    "fnClick": function (nButton, oConfig, oFlash) {
                        var selected = $('#dblist').find(":selected").text();
                        tablefill(selected);
                    }
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Export",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                }]
        }
    }).columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        aoColumns: [
            null,
            {"type": "text","bRegex": true,"bSmart": true},
            {"type": "text","bRegex": true,"bSmart": true},
            {"type": "text","bRegex": true,"bSmart": true},
            {"type": "text","bRegex": true,"bSmart": true},
            {"type": "text","bRegex": true,"bSmart": true},
            null
       ]
        });
};

    <body>
    <div id="stable" style=" margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%; display:none;">
        <table class="display" id="table_id" style="width: inherit;">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th></th>
                     <th>Unique ID</th>
                     <th>Source</th>
                     <th>App</th>
                     <th>Destination</th>
                     <th>Disposition</th>
                     <th></th>          
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Call Date</th>
                     <th>Unique ID</th>
                     <th>Source</th>
                     <th>App</th>
                     <th>Destination</th>
                     <th>Disposition</th>
                     <th>Duration</th>          
                 </tr>
            </thead>                             
            <tbody></tbody>            
        </table>
    </div>           
</body>
```

This is my css on the table

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataTables/media/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataTables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools.css" />
```

Comment: I can provide credentials to see the page that is having the problem. To better help.

Comment: Willing to toss 10 dollars at someones paypal for the fix to this. :)